# escaped characters ignored in regex character class

Tags: regex, json, r

A colleague gave me a delimited file.  One column contains JSON-like key/value pairs.  I would like to parse them into lists.  Unfortunately, the colleagues' JSON notation doesn't seem to match **rjson**'s expectations.

```
jsonString <- "{person:[Santa],location:[NorthPole]}"
fromJSON(jsonString)
Error in fromJSON(jsonString) : 
  unexpected character "p"; expecting opening string quote (") for key value
```

So I decided to do some regular expression cleanup, converting the square brackets into quotation marks.  I can replace '[' with '"', but I'm having trouble replacing '[' and ']' in the same operation:

```
gsub(pattern = "\\[", replacement = '"', x = jsonString)
[1] "{person:\"Santa],location:\"NorthPole]}"
```

Character classes ARE possible:

```
gsub(pattern = "[aeiou]", replacement = '"', x = jsonString)
[1] "{p\"rs\"n:[S\"nt\"],l\"c\"t\"\"n:[N\"rthP\"l\"]}"
```

But in the case, the brackets aren't detected:

```
gsub(pattern = "[\\[\\]]", replacement = '"', x = jsonString)
[1] "{person:[Santa],location:[NorthPole]}"
```

**I'm also open to other, non-regex solutions for parsing the JSON-like strings into R data objects.**

Comment: Try: `gsub(pattern = "\\[|]", replacement = '"', x = jsonString)`

Comment: Which `fromJSON` are you using?  There are at least three packages that contain a function by that name

Comment: @nicola Good idea.  That works, but for including more then two characters in the class, I think I would prefer to use the [] notation.

Comment: @RichardScriven: rjson

Comment: @MarkMiller then use `gsub(pattern = "[]\\[]", replacement = '"', x = jsonString)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is sufficiently general but it works on your simple case:

```
> require(RJSONIO)
Loading required package: RJSONIO
> qjson <- gsub(patt="(\\w+)", repl='"\\1"', gsub("[][]", "", jsonString) )
> fromJSON(qjson)
     person    location 
    "Santa" "NorthPole"
```

Takes out all "[" and "]" and puts in double-quotes around all "words". The character-class handling of the "[" and "]" characters is position-within-string-sensitive. To match a literal-"]" it needs to be first and to match literal-"[" it needs to be anywhere but first. See `?regex` section on character-classes.

Comment: That's really what I need for now.  I'll keep my eye out for generalization issues.

Comment: As expected:  spaces within values breaks this otherwise good suggestion... jsonString <- "{person:[Santa],location:[North Pole]}"
 ... fromJSON(gsub(patt="(\\w+)", repl='"\\1"', gsub("[][]", "", jsonString))) ... Error in fromJSON(gsub(patt = "(\\w+)", repl = "\"\\1\"", gsub("[][]",  : 
  unexpected character: "

Comment: If you wanted spaces to not break, you can replace the patt argument with ........... `"[[:alpha:] ]+"` or even `"[[:alnum:] ]+"` or `"[[:alnum:] -_]+"`

Comment: With [[:alnum:] ]+, I was able to parse my set of 750k biomedical term pairs.  I think I'm in good shape now to modify this approach as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly why, but setting `perl=TRUE` seems to fix is

```
gsub(pattern = "[\\[\\]]", replacement = '"', x = jsonString, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "{person:\"Santa\",location:\"NorthPole\"}"
```

must be something different how the base interpreter parses the character class.

You can also try extracting the data directly with regular expressions. Here I use the [regcapturedmatches](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/10413321) helper function.

```
m<-gregexpr("(\\w+):\\[([^]]*)\\]", jsonString, perl=T)
regcapturedmatches(jsonString , m)

# [[1]]
#      [,1]       [,2]       
# [1,] "person"   "Santa"    
# [2,] "location" "NorthPole"
```

Comment: I did this too, but it still won't parse with `fromJSON`, but I guess that's not the real question

Comment: Right, "real" JSON file have quotes about the element names as well. (ie `"person": "Santa"`)

Comment: Anybody want to suggest a way to convert my colleague's notation into real JSON?